# Gradle Jacoco sources include tests

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I have a multimodule project and some TestNG tests, covering them.

My gradle config looks like:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    jacocoTestReport {
        additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
        classDirectories =  files(sourceSets.main.output)
        sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)

        reports {
            html.enabled = true
            xml.enabled = true
            csv.enabled = false
        }
    }

    test {
        useTestNG()
    }

    test.finalizedBy(project.tasks.jacocoTestReport)
}
```

In the report I expected to see code coverage based on sources from main package (provided by sourceSets.main),however all java classes from test package are also included. So the coverage result is invalid.

How can the config be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my tests had a naming pattern, so I could exclude them by regex:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories =  files(sourceSets.main.output)
    sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: 'path/to/test/*Test.java')
        })
    }

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = true
        csv.enabled = false
    }
}
```